# Union of two lists of dictionaries containing lists

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
lst1 = [{u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 7223.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 37550.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 1},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 6, u'TotalTimeSpent': 23497.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 2},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 10, u'TotalTimeSpent': 36453.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 3},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 22, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 4800.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 4},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 11879.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 924.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 8075.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 5},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 426.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1528.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 6},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 8, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 7}]  
lst2 = [{u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 3, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 127.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 107.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 1},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 3.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 7, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 14.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 2},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 85.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 0, u'TotalVisits': 10, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1634.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 3},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 10, u'TotalTimeSpent': 719.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 2.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 4},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 23, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 32.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 20, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 322.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 21, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 5},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 548.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 40.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 6},
        {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 3, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 5324.0},
                    {u'HourOfDay': 20, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 45.0}],
         u'DayOfWeek': 7}]
```

They are separated by DayOfWeek and the Hours list contains dicts, each with different data for different hours of the day. Both lists are for separate data. I want to add the total time spent and visits in these two lists and create a new similar list out of it. I.e. if HourOfDay for the same DayOfWeek is the same then add the TotalTimeSpent and total visits, else append the info to the Hours list.  I do not want to miss out on any data, just append the two as they might not have data for some hours of the day, but I still want them in the final one.

What I want is the union of the two lists for every day and if the HourOfDay field is the same for the two sets on the same DayOfWeek, then add the TotalVisits and TotalTimeSpent.

I've tried:

```
final = lst1[::]  
i = j = 0  
for item1, item2 in zip(lst1,lst2):  
    for hr1 in item1["Hours"]: 
        for hr2 in item2["Hours"]:  
            if hr1["HourOfDay"] == hr2["HourOfDay"]:  
                print "i: {0} ;; j: {1}".format(i,j)  
                final[i]["Hours"][j]["TotalTimeSpent"] = hr1["TotalTimeSpent"] + hr2["TotalTimeSpent"]  
        j += 1  
    i += 1  
    j = 0  

print final
```

But it adds them up and leaves out values in the Hours list of every dict in lst2 that do not exist in lst1 because of obvious reasons. Please help!

Comment: Can you share any of your attempts at solving this? Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: By the way, there is a syntax error in your `list1`. There was an extra closing bracket in there somewhere.

Comment: That was an error here while copy pasting and editing. Corrected it!

Comment: Do you know what I should add to correct the code? So that I get values from lst2 as well?

Comment: @zezollo Thanks man!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I suggest changing the structure of your dictionary, if you can. As it is, it's hideous.

Comment: @Shiva What should I change it to? - To retain all information and make life simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution using your current data structure, which personally I think is silly because it combines the worst aspects of a list with the worst aspects of a dictionary:

```
final = [] 
for d1,d2 in zip(list1,list2):
    new = {'DayOfWeek':d1['DayOfWeek'], 'Hours':[]}
    d1copy = d1['Hours'][:]
    d2copy = d2['Hours'][:]
    for hr1 in d1['Hours']:
        for hr2 in d2['Hours']:
            if hr1["HourOfDay"] == hr2["HourOfDay"]:
                ttspent = hr1["TotalTimeSpent"] + hr2["TotalTimeSpent"]
                tvisits = hr1['TotalVisits'] + hr2['TotalVisits']
                combo = {'HourOfDay':hr1['HourOfDay'], 
                         'TotalTimeSpent':ttspent,
                         'TotalVisits':tvisits}
                new['Hours'].append(combo)
                d1copy.remove(hr1)
                d2copy.remove(hr2)
    new['Hours'].extend(d1copy)
    new['Hours'].extend(d2copy)
    final.append(new)
```

Results:

```
[{'DayOfWeek': 1,
  'Hours': [{'HourOfDay': 12, 'TotalTimeSpent': 37657.0, 'TotalVisits': 5},
   {'HourOfDay': 15, 'TotalTimeSpent': 7223.0, 'TotalVisits': 1},
   {'HourOfDay': 3, 'TotalTimeSpent': 127.0, 'TotalVisits': 2}]},
 {'DayOfWeek': 2,
  'Hours': [{'HourOfDay': 19, 'TotalTimeSpent': 23497.0, 'TotalVisits': 6},
   {'HourOfDay': 8, 'TotalTimeSpent': 3.0, 'TotalVisits': 1},
   {'HourOfDay': 7, 'TotalTimeSpent': 14.0, 'TotalVisits': 1}]},
 {'DayOfWeek': 3,
  'Hours': [{'HourOfDay': 12, 'TotalTimeSpent': 36453.0, 'TotalVisits': 10},
   {'HourOfDay': 8, 'TotalTimeSpent': 85.0, 'TotalVisits': 1},
   {'HourOfDay': 0, 'TotalTimeSpent': 1634.0, 'TotalVisits': 10}]},
 {'DayOfWeek': 4,
  'Hours': [{'HourOfDay': 13, 'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0, 'TotalVisits': 22},
   {'HourOfDay': 13, 'TotalTimeSpent': 4800.0, 'TotalVisits': 3},
   {'HourOfDay': 8, 'TotalTimeSpent': 719.0, 'TotalVisits': 10},
   {'HourOfDay': 17, 'TotalTimeSpent': 2.0, 'TotalVisits': 1}]},
 {'DayOfWeek': 5,
  'Hours': [{'HourOfDay': 9, 'TotalTimeSpent': 11879.0, 'TotalVisits': 5},
   {'HourOfDay': 8, 'TotalTimeSpent': 924.0, 'TotalVisits': 1},
   {'HourOfDay': 19, 'TotalTimeSpent': 8075.0, 'TotalVisits': 1},
   {'HourOfDay': 23, 'TotalTimeSpent': 32.0, 'TotalVisits': 2},
   {'HourOfDay': 20, 'TotalTimeSpent': 322.0, 'TotalVisits': 3},
   {'HourOfDay': 21, 'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0, 'TotalVisits': 1}]},
 {'DayOfWeek': 6,
  'Hours': [{'HourOfDay': 19, 'TotalTimeSpent': 426.0, 'TotalVisits': 1},
   {'HourOfDay': 14, 'TotalTimeSpent': 1528.0, 'TotalVisits': 1},
   {'HourOfDay': 8, 'TotalTimeSpent': 548.0, 'TotalVisits': 1},
   {'HourOfDay': 17, 'TotalTimeSpent': 40.0, 'TotalVisits': 2}]},
 {'DayOfWeek': 7,
  'Hours': [{'HourOfDay': 17, 'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0, 'TotalVisits': 8},
   {'HourOfDay': 3, 'TotalTimeSpent': 5324.0, 'TotalVisits': 3},
   {'HourOfDay': 20, 'TotalTimeSpent': 45.0, 'TotalVisits': 2}]}]
```

Comment: In addition to this, might I recommend changing the structure of your data, OP? 
For example, your `lst1` could look like `[{1 : {'Hours' : [...] }, 2 :  {'Hours' : [...] }, ...]`
This way, you can easily index your dictionary by the day of the week. Dictionaries are meant to enable easy access to data, not hinder it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really strange dict structure, and you're even using a non-zero-based numerical scale for days of the week.  It took me a while to parse your data structure, but here's what's going on:

lst1 and lst2 are structured as lists of objects like this: [{object Day 1}, {object Day 2}, ... {object Day 7}]

Each object in those lists can be further decomposed as an object with two keys -- "hours" and "DayOfWeek":

```
object for Day x = {
    Hours: [list of other objects with keys for HourOfDay, TotalVisits, and TotalTimeSpent],
    DayOfWeek: x }
```

That said, it's not memory efficient to use lists of dicts as you have, so I'd suggest using a multidimensional list for fast retrieval and updating.

```
# Create a new list of lists that will be accessible by [day][hour]
#      This 7 x 24 array will contain dicts containing data for TotalVisits and TotalTimeSpent.  
#      This will permit O(1) retrieval for relevant entries by day & hour
#      I've included _Day and _Hour in the dict for the sake of readability 
#       (if you have more time, you can even make these immutable with a Base class)

newObject = [[{'_Day':i,'_Hour':j,'TotalVisits':0,'TotalTimeSpent':0}  \
                   for j in range(0,24)] for i in range(1,8)]

# Iterate over items in lst1, lst2 and add data to our new object
#    Don't forget to adjust the index for your days so that you don't get 
#       an index-out-of-bounds error.  
#   (Yet another reason why you should number your days 0-6 instead of 1-7.)

combinedList = lst1 + lst2
for item in combinedList:
    day = item['DayOfWeek']  # This will return an int 1-7; needs to be adjusted to zero-scale
    visitEntries = item['Hours'] # This will return a list of dicts
    for i in visitEntries:
          hour = i['HourOfDay']
          # Add visit data to our new object for each day, hour
          newObject[day-1][hour]['TotalVisits'] += i['TotalVisits']
          newObject[day-1][hour]['TotalTimeSpent'] += i['TotalTimeSpent']

# To see results:
for i in range(0,7):
    for j in range(0,24):
         print newObject[day][hour]
```